# Return valid JSON data from Cassandra (Akka HTTP)

Tags: json, scala, cassandra, akka, akka-http

Data from Cassandra database is coming back as invalid JSON despite having the JSON flag in the SELECT statement.

Here is what I receive:

When my front-end receives this it is of course considered invalid JSON. Also I'm not sure why `"[json]"` is there.

```
Future(Success(["[json]":'{"pasta_name": "conchiglie", "id": 2, "description": "description for conchiglie", "image": {"alt": "alt text", "src": "image.jpg"}}']))
```

Here's what I would like to receive:

```
{
    "pasta_name": "conchiglie",
    "id": 2, "description":
    "description for conchiglie",
    "image": 
        {
            "alt": "alt text", 
            "src": "image.jpg"
        }
}
```

Here is my simplified code

```
object Server extends App {

implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("helloworld")
implicit val executor: ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.global
implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

val sessionSettings = CassandraSessionSettings()
implicit val cassandraSession: CassandraSession =
    CassandraSessionRegistry.get(system).sessionFor(sessionSettings)

val recipes: Future[String] =
    CassandraSource(s"SELECT JSON * FROM danlough.recipe_by_pasta").map(row => row.getFormattedContents()).runWith(Sink.head)

import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
  def route = path("getRecipe") {
    get {
      respondWithHeaders(RawHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000"), RawHeader("Vary", "Origin")) {
        complete(recipes)
      }
    }
  }

Http().bindAndHandle(route, host, port)
```

Comment: I think you might need to extract it using `row.getString("[json]")`

Comment: Above comments are good. First comment above lead to correct answer and second comment above is a correctly solved my issue. Thank you. `row.getString(0)` also worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `row => row.getFormattedContents()` to `row => row.getString(0)` to extract only field that contains JSON formatted by Cassandra, instead of returning the string formatted as CQL that happens when you do `row.getFormattedContents()`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. `row.getString("[json]")` also worked.